# Issue with updating objects using the "accessLevel" parameter of Database.update method

Tags: apex, record-access-level

We are updating our code to use the new `accessLevel` parameter in the `update` method of the `Database` class. We have cases where the object contains fields that cannot be edited (e.g. `LastModifiedDate`).

If we update the object using the normal `update`, the update works because we have not actually updated `LastModifiedDate`. However, if we use `Database.update` with `AccessLevel.USER_MODE`, we see the exception:

`System.DmlException: Operation failed due to fields being inaccessible on Sobject Account, check errors on Exception or Result!`

Sample code we have used is as below. The debug message prints:
`The field(s) "LastModifiedDate" are not accessible for update of Account`

```
Account acc = new Account(name='Acc1');
insert acc;

acc = [select id, name, lastModifiedDate from Account where id = :acc.id];
acc.name = 'Acc1_updated';
update acc;

try {
    Database.update(acc, AccessLevel.USER_MODE);
} catch (DMLException dex) {
    System.debug('The field(s) "' + 
    String.join(dex.getDmlFieldNames(0), ', ') + '" are not accessible for update of Account');
    throw dex;
}
```

Similar issue with auto numbered name fields, formula fields, master-detail lookup fields etc.

Is there any way to use `Database.update` to update the object other than removing the field `LastModifiedDate` from the SOQL query select list? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to include the `LastModifiedDate` in the query? The code you have provided is not using it

Answer (score 8):

As you have seen, you cannot include `LastModifiedDate` when doing an update in user mode. The easiest way to fix this would be to create a new Account in Apex and use that to update. For example:

```
acc = [SELECT Id, Name, LastModifiedDate FROM Account WHERE Id = :accId];
Account accountToUpdate = new Account(Id = accId, Name = 'Acc1_updated');
update as user accountToUpdate;
```

An alternative way to do this would be to use the [`stripInaccessible`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_stripInaccessible.htm) method. For example:

```
List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name, LastModifiedDate FROM Account WHERE Id = :accId];
accList[0].Name = 'Acc1_updated';
Account accToUpdate = Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.UPDATEABLE, accList).getRecords()[0];
update as user accToUpdate;
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. 

The sample code is a simplified code snippet written to easily explain the issue. We have a number of cases where we have queried auto numbered name fields, formula fields, master-detail look fields etc. It will be a lot of work to update the code to create objects without those readonly fields and then update. Since we are not updating those fields in the objects I was hoping for a simpler alternative.

Comment: @BrijeshPopat There is no alternative.  If you include the field in the query, it is in the object and will be included in the update, even if you set the value to null.

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth feeding this back to Salesforce? I have had this issue myself and it's frustrating.

Comment: Security.stripInaccessible seems to be the best option available. We will try that. Thanks.

Comment: I've just sent this link to some friends at Salesforce - it does seem a bit odd that to use some new features that save code we have to add more code in other places.

Comment: This seems like a bug. For the time being, it seems that you'll have to use `Security.stripInaccessible()`