# fflib CRUD check conflicts with Flow System Context

Tags: screen-flow, guest-user, fflib, system

I have built a simple POC flow Flow - specifically creating and updating an account when the flow is running in System Mode Without Sharing - **but using the Experience Cloud Guest Site User**.

When I run it in Sys Mode on the Public Site, I can create and update an Account. But if I do a CRUD check in Apex via an invocable class during the flow, it says the GSU doesn't have access to update an account. I know all too well that GSU can't be granted update access via Perms any more, but I guess I assumed that if the flow elevates the permission, the Schema.sObjectType.Account.isUpdateable() would somehow come back as true, since the flow has effectively granted that access.

The reason this becomes an issue is that customer is using a managed package where the trigger is using fflib, and performs a CRUD check on a trigger as required by Security Review. But that crud is failing on update because it reports false even though the Flow will actually let the user perform an update - and I can't work out how to avoid that conflict without the ISV providing some means of bypassing the check?

Comment: Sadly flow's run settings do not impact invocable methods, which I feel is a product gap. They only impact standard elements that care (such as Get Records or Update Records). One option would be to use a platform event, created and "published" in the flow, to run your logic in the context of a different user.

Comment: I have to ask - is the trigger using DML for some related object, and hence the CRUD/FLS checks?

Comment: I had similar issue in an fflib org and went with @PhilW's approach - the Flow delegated work to a Platform Event that was configured to run as a user with sufficient CRUD permissions.

Comment: @Phil - Since it is managed, not 100% sure - but that's the sense I get from the ISVs response

Comment: @cropredy - I think the challenge here is that is is designed to be an application process with various additional related records and updates that depend on answers - so something flow is great for - unless you need it to happen via GSU.

I suspect what we end up doing is writing it all to a staging table with no trigger etc., and then firing the event at the end so that it can all be converted without hitting any limits - clunky but should be reliable

Comment: that's what I did -- GSU Flow saved data in a custom object; then flow delegated work to the PE passing the Id of the custom object; PE subscriber trigger then did all the ensuing work. I wasn't chuffed about this as it increased the test method work to be done but it works great

Comment: I must say, the ISV seems to have done something strange, from what you said. They should have written the processing to do what it can, silently leaving out processing if not permitted. Or is it that you need this to happen and it doesn't because of the permission check?

Comment: @phil w I think this is a core part of the processing, so it needs to happen - and would only fails in this scenario (it is a site license so would normally be available for all users)

Comment: Well, at least you have a workaround outlined by cropredy and me; that said, I'd raise this with the ISV and see if they can provide a means to allow use with guest users.

Comment: @philw - you should answer this as you were "first"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly flow's run settings do not impact invocable methods or other Apex that they cause to be executed, which I feel is a product gap. They only impact standard elements that care (such as Get Records or Update Records).

One option would be to use a platform event, created and "published" in the flow, to run your logic in the context of a different user.

You have a couple of options for that - make the flow only generate a platform event that has the logic implemented in an Apex trigger based subscriber or, as suggested by @cropredy, have the flow do the logic needed but against custom objects that the platform event subscriber translates to the real objects in question.

The latter has the disadvantage of duplication of data structures and the problem that the events are async, so if the flow is doing more that needs to run against side effects of the data insert/update, you get into a tangle.

The former has the disadvantage that the event is async too, so all processing from the point of data manipulation must be in the trigger.

BTW, the platform event subscriber must be Apex, not flow, in order to run as a different user. That said, you could have the Apex subscriber go invoke a flow if you want the logic to be defined in a flow. That explicitly invoked flow will run as the automated process user (or other nominated user).

Comment: Thanks - wasn't aware of this limitation:
"BTW, the platform event subscriber must be Apex, not flow, in order to run as a different user."

Comment: We need "cheap" async processing (at high volume, more than async limits) but with appropriate user-specific permissions and sharing, and using a flow PE subscriber allows this.