# Reliable Detection of an Automated Process User

Tags: platform-event, automated-process, user-mode

Because [User Mode database operations don't work for the Automated Process User](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/414051/automated-process-user-and-accesslevel-usermode-should-it-lose-access/415204#415204), I need to litter my code with checks to see if the current user is such a user.

I've previously got an automated process user ID with the following:

```
return [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND UserType = 'AutomatedProcess' AND Username LIKE '%autoproc%' LIMIT 1].Id;
```

I don't know if there can be more than one such user, but I'm going to change to use something like this:

```
Boolean isAutoProc = [SELECT Id
                      FROM User
                      WHERE Id = : UserInfo.getUserId()
                      AND Usertype = 'AutomatedProcess'].size() > 0;
```

Of course, rather than litter my code I'll likely refactor to put a wrapper around all database operations (queries and DML ops), but what I want to check is whether this approach is legitimate or whether I'm missing some key piece of information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the user type without a query:

```
Boolean isAutomatedUser = UserInfo.getUserType() == 'automatedprocess';
```

I'd probably use a static variable to control that:

```
static AccessLevel access = UserInfo.getUserType() == 'automatedprocess'
  ? AccessLevel.SYSTEM_MODE
  : AccessLevel.USER_MODE;
```

That way, I could just refer to the variable:

```
Database.update(someRecords, Utils.access);
```

Comment: Gah, I didn't look at those methods. Had it in my head I'd looked for that before and not seen it. The static option makes a lot of sense. Thanks, and Happy New Year mate.

Comment: @MattLacey That's why, even with nearly two decades experience in Apex, I still check the docs on a regular basis. Hard to keep up with all the changes .

Answer (score 1):

In the question, you mention that "I don't know if there can be more than one such user".

There definitely can be more than one user with a `UserType=AutomatedProcess`.

In a scratch org, you get two:

- Automated Process
- Data.com Clean

Brian's answer to your question of detecting whether or not the current user is automated is spot-on and the best way of doing it.

But to answer your side-question, and if anyone is thinking of querying for "Automated Process" (i.e. the default user for Platform Events et al.), then the way to do that is to query like this:

```
Id automatedProcessUserId = [
       SELECT Id
       FROM User
       WHERE UserType = 'AutomatedProcess'
       AND Username = : 'autoproc@' + UserInfo.getOrganizationId()
       LIMIT 1].Id;
```

The username of Automated Process User is defined to be `autoproc@<org-id>`.

Comment: Thanks mate, that coffee will be on me when we manage it!