Issue with AccessLevel.USER_MODE in update DML
I am facing an issue with the below code when executing on anonymous window.
Account acc = new Account(Name='AccName');
Database.Insert(acc);
Database.insert(new Contact(LastName='last', firstName =' first', AccountId=acc.Id));
Contact[] cnts = [SELECT Name, Account.Name, FirstName FROM Contact];
cnts[0].FirstName = 'changedFName';
Database.update(cnts, AccessLevel.USER_MODE);

Error received:

System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 003IR00001jOkHTYA0; first error: INVALID_FIELD, Cannot specify both an external ID reference Account and a salesforce id, AccountId: []

Additional information:
When we remove AccessLevel.USER_MODE, the above query works fine. I also have few workarounds in place, but I want to know if this is the way access levels with DML are designed. I understand that we can't include other objects in update operation, but removing access level from Database.update allows this functionality.
Query:
Can you explain if this is working as designed, I could not locate any documentation for the same.

USER_MODE seems to be funny about you querying and then updating. See also: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/412741/issue-with-updating-objects-using-the-accesslevel-parameter-of-database-update/412743#412743
